# Why is my function not working in phtml file?

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.9, adminhtml

I have created a `collection.php` model and added a `addOrderFilter()` function, but when I try to call `addOrderFilter()` in my phtml file, it gives me

`Fatal error: Call to a member function addOrderFilter() on boolean in [...]\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\paketid\shipping.phtml on line 5`

This is my `shipping.phtml` :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('PaketId_Shipping');?>
<h1>Test custom block</h1>
<?php $order = $this->getOrder()?>
<?php $shipping = Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection()->addOrderFilter($order) ?>
<?php if(count($shipping)):
foreach($shipping as $shipping): ?>
<?php echo $this->__('Booking Code') ;?>
<?php echo $shipping->getBookingCode(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My `collection.php` model :

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
protected $order;

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result');
}

public function addOrderFilter($order)
{
    if ($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $order = (int) $order->getId();
    }
    if (!is_array($order)) {
        $order = array($order);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.order_id IN (?)", $order);
    //$this->getSelect()->where("main_table.order_id IN (?)", $order)->order('id DESC');

    return $this;
}
```

The confusing part is, why does my phtml doesn't render my `collection` model ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure magento is not running in compilation mode.

OR

There is something wrong in syntax `Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection()` . This is not returning correct collection object. Try debugging whether it returns collection object or not.

OR

You can try different similar syntax

```
Mage::getResourceModel('paketid_shipping/result_collection')->addOrderFilter($order);
```

Comment: it gives me `bool(false)` when i try to `var_dump(Mage::'paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection()` and I get the same error when try changing my code into `Mage::getResourceModel('paketid_shipping/result_collection')->addOrderFilter($order);`

Comment: i dont get the `make sure magento is not running in compilation mode` part :(